# Programatically accessing block settings

Tags: blocks

Is it possible in Drupal 7 to load block visibility settings programatically in module? I'm rendering block programatically and I want to include checking those settings, so it still will be possible to hide block from UI. Property of "status" and "visibility" are not enough, since it's possible that the block won't be placed in any region at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, [`block_load`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_load/7.x) gives you the contents of the whole row from the `block` table:

```
$block = block_load('module', 'delta');

$region = $block->region;
$weight = $block->weight;
$custom = $block->custom;
$visibility = $block->visibility;
$pages = $block->pages;
$title = $block->title;
```

And so on.

Comment: This is the only thing this object contains:
`bid -> 187,
  module -> block,
  delta -> 20,
  theme -> galeco,
  status -> 0,
  weight -> 0,
  region -> ,
  custom -> 0,
  visibility -> 0,
  pages -> ,
  title -> <none>,
  cache -> -1,
  i18n_mode -> 1`

Visibility and Status values are already computed, so if the block is turned off they will give me 0, even if the rest of visibility settings state that the block should be displayed. That's why I neeed granural acess to settings. I stated that  status and visibility properties are not enough in my initial post.

Comment: What are _the rest of the visibility settings_? Do you mean "Roles" and "Content type"? Those are in the `block_role` and `block_node_type` tables respectively

Comment: By visibility settings I mean visibility settings as shown here http://prntscr.com/hzdjku The actual settings, not computed value whether block should be displayed or not. In this case I'm mostly interested in block_roles if that's what stores data from Roles tab in Visibility settings. Is there a function to load it per block, or should I just get it from database by query?

Comment: Just get it from the DB, there’s no helper in the api